# JPA/Hibernate @SequenceGenerator: negative sequence support

Tags: hibernate, jpa, generator, sequence

I have a negative sequence in DB (-1, -2, -3, etc) and I want to use it for generating IDs for my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
@SequenceGenerator(name="foo_seq", sequenceName="negative_seq", allocationSize=1)
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="foo_seq")
    private Long id;
}
```

The problem is that `SequenceHiLoGenerator` is used and it enters the infinite loop in the `generate` method in the following piece of code:

```
while ( value == null || value.lt( 0 ) ) {
    value = super.generateHolder( session );
}
```

Does it mean that negative sequence are not supported by Hibernate? Or am I doing something wrong? I didn't find any mention in Hibernate documentation about using negative sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decreasing sequence generators are not supported, no.  But it is easy to add your own `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator` implementation to do that.  Let's call it `org.my.DecreasingSequenceGenerator`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
@GenericGenerator(
    name="my_seq",
    strategy="org.my.DecreasingSequenceGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter( name="sequence", value="negative_seq" ),
        ...
    }
)
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="my_seq")
    private Long id;
}
```

passing in whatever parameterization you want your `DecreasingSequenceGenerator` implementation to have.